# Formatting Json Code in Java

Tags: java, json, post

I need to convert the following Json code into Java.

```
{
    "service": {
        "type": "nyd",
        "discount": 0.20,
        "items": [
            {
                "asin": "....",
                "link": "http://amazon.com/.....",
                "quantity": 2
            },
            // ...
        ],
        // See /addresses
        "shipping_address": {
            "full_name": "Mr Smith",
            "street1": "Some Mission St",
            "street2": "",   // Optional
            "city": "San Francisco",
            "state": "CA",
            "zip": "94000",
            "country": "US",
            "phone": "1234567890"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently implementing this by using the following code:

```
    String       postUrl       = "https://API.example.com";
    Gson         gson          = new Gson();
    HttpClient   httpClient    = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();


    HttpPost     httpPostRequest  = new HttpPost(postUrl);

            StringEntity postingString = new StringEntity("{\"service\" : {\"type\":\"nnn\", \"discount\":" +  0.2 + ",\"items\" : [ { \"asin\":\"B018Y1XXT6\", \"link\":\"https://www.amazon.com/Yubico-Y-159-YubiKey-4-Nano/dp/B018Y1XXT6/\", \"quantity\":" + 1 +  " } ],  \"shipping_address\" : {\"full_name\":\"Steven Smith\", \"street1\":\"11 Man Rd\", \"street2\":\"\", \"city\":\"Woonsocket\", \"state\":\"RI\", \"zip\":\"02844\", \"country\":\"US\", \"phone\":\"7746536483\" } } } "); 


    Mote: the values are different but I'm trying to achieve the same syntax.


    System.out.println("Post String value: " + IOUtils.toString(postingString.getContent()));



    httpPostRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Token " + apiKey);

    httpPostRequest.setEntity(postingString);
    httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    //httpPostRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    HttpResponse  response = httpClient.execute(httpPostRequest);

    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

The "postString" value is:

```
 {"service" : {"type":"nnn", "discount":0.2,"items" : [ { "asin":"B018Y1XXT6", "link":"https://www.amazon.com/Yubico-Y-159-YubiKey-4-Nano/dp/B018Y1XXT6/", "quantity":1 } ],  "shipping_address" : {"full_name":"Steven Smith", "street1":"11 Man Rd", "street2":"", "city":"Woonsocket", "state":"RI", "zip":"02844", "country":"US", "phone":"17746536483" } } }
```

However, when I attempt to submit the request I get a Bad Request error.

How can I format the String correctly?

Thanks

Comment: `Service =` looks suspect to me. service is part of the json object so I think your StringEntity should start with `{\"service\":   ` and have the corresponding terminating curly brace at the end. It seems like the postString value should be `{"service":{"type":"nyd", " ....`

Answer (score 0):

You have sent an incorrect json String if you want to go with the json provided .Following are the errors:

1) "service = {\"type\" should be **{\"service\" : {\"type**

2) discount should not be a string
   \"discount\":\"0.2\", should be **\"discount\":" + 0.2 + ",**

3) items = [ should be **\"items\" : [**

4) quantity should not be string
\"quantity\":\"1\"  }  should be **\"quantity\":" + 1 + "}**

5) comma missing before shipping address key
] shipping_address = should be **], \"shipping_address\" :**

6) add one more **}** at the end

Comment: Thank you! I modified the Json String according to what you wrote:     {"service" : {"type":"nyd", "discount":0.2,"items" : [ { "asin":"B018Y1XXT6", "link":"https://www.amazon.com/Yubico-Y-159-YubiKey-4-Nano/dp/B018Y1XXT6/", "quantity":1 } ],  "shipping_address" : {"full_name":"Steven Smith", "street1":"1221 Male Rd", "street2":"", "city":"Woonsocket", "state":"RI", "zip":"02844", "country":"US", "phone":"17746536483" } } }  but I am still receiving Bad Request error.

Comment: One more thing, remove the semi colon at the end of the link "amazon.com/Yubico-Y-159-YubiKey-4-Nano/dp/B018Y1XXT6‌​/"**;**,

Comment: Also recheck your Url, Auth Values and check the exact response code using response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()

Comment: I don't know why a semi colon appears at the end of link. In my code there is none.  Stackoverlfow is adding the semi colon but it does not appear in the String I'm using. The exact response code is 400.